# Mac Pro early 2008 doesn't boot anymore

Tags: startup, mac-pro, macos

I got a Mac Pro early 2008 2x 2.8 quad-core for 12 years now. A few weeks ago, it stopped booting after 5 seconds. I restarted it and it was ok. But the problem came more and more often the next days, and today it just doesn't boot anymore. It stops after only 2 seconds. I've noticed that the CPU **LEDS 5 & 6** flash in sync one time at the very end, when the fans stop with a last 'clic'.
I tried everything I could do before posting this question, I mean unplug all hardwares, cleaning, and I followed the very complete answer from @monomeeth [Boot fail diagnosis](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325307/mac-pro-3-1-boot-fail-diagnosis?answertab=active&newreg=c0a9a5a5bc7a4232a5f606a155c848fe)

When I press the DIAG_LED, I got only the **LED 2** on. So I don't know if the problem comes from the Logic Board or from the PSU... hope it's not both :(

I'm about to order a used PSU for trying, but I'd like to be sure.
The noob question is : if it's a PSU trouble, why the computer was able to start correctly sometimes ?

Thanks in advance for your precious help !

Comment: Did you change the PRAM battery yet? That's first. You'd be amazed at how much random sh** happens if that's dead. Mine [from your linked question] turned out to be a dead RAM riser board. Removed it worked fine [I had some odd results as I also had one dodgy RAM stick which confused things] Unfortunately since then the mobo died too, so I got a 'new' machine entirely, same model, fewer hours. Mine had been 24/7/365 for over 10 years.

Comment: You mean the CR2032 ? Yes brand new. I've also tried to remove the 2 risers and exchanged them. It would be crazy if they are both dead at the same time, but not impossible in fact...

Comment: reduce to one RAM stick in each & test individually. It still could be PSU or mobo… but I'd eliminate the 'easy bits' first. If you can't self-diagnose easily, I'd compare prices of individual PSU & mobo against that of a full 'new' machine.

Comment: Did it without success... you're right about a new machine, but the PSU I found is 50€ only, so I could give it a chance :)

Comment: OK, that's a reasonable price - but I'd still weigh it against being able to get a whole replacement machine for €250 - especially if it turns out not to be that, so next would be the mobo… ad infinitum. I fought mine on & off for a year but eventually gave in. Now I have one for 'spares'… though I still don't know which bit finally failed ;)

Comment: What are the symptoms of a dead mobo ?

Comment: I honestly don't know - as I have no real way to measure these things I'd call it "when you've changed everything else & it still doesn't work properly" ;-)

Comment: I mean your computer was starting a little moment or nothing at all ?

Comment: I can't remember now. I went through so many tests & changes I've lost track. I eventually got it going, removing the bad RAM riser, only for it to fail again 6 months later & it was then cheaper [assuming I'm charging myself for my own time] to just replace it than keep fighting it.

Comment: In waiting my new PSU, I tried to replace the video card with an other reference just for trying : same thing first, then I tried again and it booted normally but the screen has remained black. So I've replug the original card and it worked. Strange behavior... No when I press the DIAG_LED, the last one doesn't light up.

Comment: Was your replacement CPU a Mac card [or at least properly Mac-flashed] & of an appropriate age? Otherwise it will stay black until login, or may fail totally if the card is really too 'new.

Comment: No, it's still a Radeon 2600 XT but it's not exactly the same... it has one more round plug next to the 2 DVI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new PSU did the job ! The EFI led is still off but everything works fine now :)