# 2008 Mac Pro 3,1 freezes upon adding USB devices

Tags: shutdown, reboot

On my 2008 Mac Pro 3,1 it will turn off and have to be restarted when adding a usb ext drive.  It has even turned off when plugging in a wired Apple mouse as well.

It does this in either front or back.  I have reset the battery inside and the pram and cmu.

How can I stop it from turning off like this?

Comment: "reset the battery" you mean replaced? 12 years is old for a battery & failed batteries can give all kinds of apparently random issues.

Comment: it shows a errB led lit up in the computer on the main board.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325307/mac-pro-3-1-boot-fail-diagnosis