# Mac Pro 3,1 Power Up No Chime Nor Boot

Tags: startup, hardware, battery, mac-pro

My Early 2008 Mac Pro won't boot.  Won't do much, actually.  This is what I've done:

- replaced the power supply
- removed DVD player
- removed all RAM
- removed all video cards (I have a handful of wonderful flavours)
- no drive at all (although I have a single HD with fresh test OS (I forget which OS though, but compatible as I've had it running on this box)
- replaced the CR032 battery with a tested battery having ~3V

BTW I've been referring to [Mac Pro Service Source Manual](http://tim.id.au/laptops/apple/macpro/macpro.pdf) but it has a different LED layout, so it's extra confusing.

The box powers-up, with the fans spinning, front LED solid white.  Nothing else.  No chime.  Tried pushing the `SYS_RST` and nothing happens.  I'll include an actual pic of my LEDs when in this state.

[image]

Not sure what to do at this point.  Any insight appreciated how I can make this do something.  It is sitting in my garage which is ~6°C at the moment, so it's not overheating at all half a second before startup.  BTW I thought the similar white button TOP RIGHT of the motherboard was the SYS_RST, not the one in the image.  I need some clarification on that.

[image: It sits here on my desk]

Comment: That pic doesn't look like a 3,1 Have you double-checked it's not earlier? s/n is on the lower edge of the PCI section on the back. Check against Everymac's [Ultimate Mac Lookup](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/) That button, btw, is probably the LED test button [though it's at the wrong and for a 3,1] The reset is way up in the top right corner.

Comment: Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325307/mac-pro-3-1-boot-fail-diagnosis

Comment: @Tetsujin https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=A1186 Original owner.  I also said it was top right.  I used top right and it did nothing.  I've read that post before with no LEDs on, and tried everything.  I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Your search on model number brings up all Mac Pros before the 4,1. Model number is always a bad lookup criterion, they're shared across many models. Serial number is more accurate. Enter serial #, then select from processor variants. Info for both is on that sticker - https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAtOV.jpg I can't find the service source for the 1,1 or 2,1 but I already have the 3, 4 & 5. Pic in the linked post was from the same Mac as the sticker pic. Now unfortunately put out to grass. BTW, you did reset the SMC after pulling components out??

Comment: Serial No: G88371UJXYK, 8 processor Model A1186.  Mac Pro 2.8 8CS/2X1G/320/2600XT/SD/BT  It's a Mac Pro 3,1.  Why do you think it's not a Mac Pro 3,1?  I'll include the SN.

Comment: …because I'd mis-remembered which end that button was, so I had to go take one apart to see. However, I'm not seeing your combative nature as being really useful to triage, so I wish you luck.

Comment: Who is combative?  I've been showing you it's a Mac Pro 3,1 all this time.  I knew it was a 3,1, said it was a 3,1, and you disagreed.  I did everything you said, and posted the picture of the SN.  Did you look it up to see it's a 3,1?  I've reset the SMC about 12 times.  I've removed the battery about 6 times.

Comment: whilst ignoring every other question I've asked.

Comment: You've asked one other question.

Comment: If the machine won't POST, it's likely the logic board.

Comment: Sorry, what does POST mean?

Comment: Power On Self Test.  All computers do this PC, Mac, Commodore...everything.  For instance, if you have a memory issue, the Mac will beep three times - it failed during POST.  The chime (which Apple has turned off as of recent) signaled that it passed POST and was beginning the boot process

Comment: So no indicators that I can see, is there any way I can investigate further?

Comment: That button near the LEDs is not "sys reset"  That button is the DIAG_LED button.  You have to press it to read the LEDs.  However, if there's an error, it should come up automatically.  If it doesn't then there's either an issue with the power supply or the power rails on the logic board not turning things on.

Comment: See this page for 2008 Mac Pro Diagnostic LEDs:  https://www.macrepaircentral.us/mac-pro-early-2008/diagnostic-leds.html

Comment: OK, now we're getting somewhere.  I thought they would automatically be on.  My reading:  2 and 9 on solid.  So "Standby (Trickle Power)", "EFI is done loading".  Should I be getting a chime?  Everything seems nominal.

Comment: EFI got loaded, so unless you turned off the chime, which is possible, you should hear the chime before it starts looking for boot devices.  If you hold the Option key, does the boot manager come up?  (Also, to notify people that you've responded, you need to @ them in your comments - i.e. @Allan).  I just happened to click back here by accident and saw the new comment.

Comment: @Allan I inserted some RAM (2 sticks), and I got a chime. It's headless at the moment.  Inserted 4 more sticks, it didn't chime.  So I'm messing around there.  Got the chime once.

Comment: Re-reading your comment, it shouldn't be in sleep mode if booting cold.  I would [reset the SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)

Comment: @Allan I usually do it once I power down.  Now I think the NVRAM needs resetting (remove battery).  I'm back to 2 sticks and no chime.

Comment: You need memory to boot.  If you got the chime, but in as little RAM as possible, boot it and install an OS.  From there you can do more and better diagnostics.

Comment: Why would your NVRAM need resetting? (It's a rhetorical question)

Comment: @Allan I have a drive waiting.  I read somewhere NO RAM, but obviously that is wrong.  So trying to get a chime going.  I've only had one chime, hence the thought of resetting NVRAM.

Comment: NVRAM sets up your preboot *environment.*  It has nothing to do with RAM, or applications, or anything like that.  It will have the boot arguments like what volume to boot or the audio volume of the chime, the screen brightness, the MAC address of the BT keyboard and the Find My Mac token.  Resetting NVRAM as a fix for everything has been spread across the Internet because it appears to magically fix things when it's really the accompanying reboot that is what the system actually needed.

Comment: You have to make sure your RAM is the correct type and speed.  Put just the bare amount necessary to boot.  Then proceed from there.

Comment: @Allan OK I can't get a chime anymore.  I've been using this box since I bought it brand new.  I've never had RAM issues.  Not new RAM.  I have two sticks in it, and I can't get the chime back, drive-in or drive-out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115573/discussion-between-rich-f-and-allan).

Comment: You don't need a drive to boot.  You need memory and CPUs.