# mac pro 3,1 no chimes power up. no keyboard cap lock light, no display signal

Tags: startup, mac-pro

My flawless 12 year old mac pro 3,1 dual 2.8 quad core mac isn't getting past fan power up!

System info:

Mac Pro 3,1 dual quad 2.8 ghz, OWC ram 32 gb, Mojave via drdos patch.
Video: nvidia gfx 680
Bay one: boot drive OWC ssd 2TB plus bootcamp partition
Bay two: softraid drive one of three 4TB
Bay three: softraid drive two of three 4TB
Bay four: softraid drive three of three 4TB
Optical bay: dvd drive shared with Two HHDs wired to the motherboard sata connectors

PCI cards:

Usb2.0 /FireWire 800 ports
Caldigit usb 3.0 and usb-c 3.1  card
Esata card.

I boot off the bay one ssd with 1.5 tb system and applications, the remain 0.5 TB is for the bootcamp. The 12 tb softraid is used for photos, media etc (I’m a photographer)

The optical bay mounted hhds are used for backup.

So like a well maintained classic Cuba car, it has a decade of upkeep. I was hoping  for it to last another year until apple sorts out the apple silly-con models.

Failure:

It started while booted in windows bootcamp, I was formatting in exfat some new usb drives. I found when formated in the actual windows dos its more compatable with windows machines than a Mac exfat format.

5 usb thumb drives needed formatting: I started with one and noticed after the format, the Mouse froze. I ctr alt del the machine to reboot into windows, it ended up needing a power cycle, using the option key boot drive selection method.

Windows bootcamp rebooted fine.

To speed up the formatting (I was low level formatting the drives) I decided to format the remaining four usb thumb drives at once, using the built in usb 2.0 slots on the Mac Pro.

As soon as they completed, and I closed the formatting window and software ejected all four drives, the mouse froze again.  Fine, the usb drives were ready  to pull out, I ctr alt del the computer, it went to a black screen.  Figuring the reboot didn’t take place, I powered down, waited 10 seconds, powered up, no chime, black screen (monitors remained on standby)

Symptoms:

Upon powering up, the power button remains lit normally.
Fans start up, first anomaly they do not go full speed as they did before the chime.
Drives spin up normally and appear to click normally.
Memory card slots red led blink once on boot up as normal
No chime
No other indicator of hardware failiure, I.e. blinking power light, white screen, etc
No power to keyboard (confirmed with capslock) via any of my USB ports, even the ones on the pci card.
I do have a usb lamp that can turn on when connected to the pci card usb, but not the built in usb.

Diagnostic LEDS:
Powered Off:  pressing the DIAG button reveals a normal LED 2 amber STBY light, indication there is trickle power from the PSU.  All others are off.
Powered On:  pressing the DIAG button reveals
a) normal LED 2 amber STBY light, and
b) LED 8 is NOT on, perhaps telling the the PSU is not supplying power during full power.
c) LED 9 is on indicating that the computer has completed the on board Extensible Firmware Interface (EFI) operations and the operating system is now in control.

All other LEDs are off.

Attempted troubleshooting:

Reseated all drives and cards.  Swapped out the gtx680 card with an nvidia 8800, the previous card that I had.
Attempted boot up with all cables and cards removed with the exception of either 8800 and 680.
I have a spare keyboard as a test, still no power to the keyboard from any USB port.

Still no chime, no power to a keyboard to present boot options, no video output (monitors remain in standby mode)

Internal system fans are spinning normal, the system feels cool inside (house temp is 68-70 deg). The machine sounds as if it’s in idle if it were in normal operation.  Air outputted from machine feels as it would idle: normal on bottom, with the power supply  fan a touch warm. Again : how it would be at idle.

I swapped out for a fresh PRAM battery, no dice

I installed a new  Power supply: 661-4677 980W-614-0409.  Same problem, no chime, no boot, no signal from display

using. 5V USB powered light, I confirmed that a USB card that I have installed outputs power, so the PCI power seems ok.

Question :

Is there any other troubleshooting that I may have missed?

Thank you for reading this.

Take care!

Comment: There's a good workthrough here - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325307/mac-pro-3-1-boot-fail-diagnosis - I'd also strip down to just a known-good boot drive, strip the RAM down to 2 in each riser [you know how funny these are on RAM placement]. I'd also reset SMC & NVRAM [overkill, but SMC can be twitchy on these] additionally test each RAM riser individually. Mine turned out to be a dead riser + 2 failing RAM chips. On one riser it ran fine for another year, but finally gave up the ghost. On the upside, I replaced it for £250 with an identical machine & that's still going strong.