# No Chime, No boot up - just fan noise on my Mac Pro 3,1

Tags: startup

I have run into a problem with my Mac Pro 3,1 in that I decided to strip down the Mac clean and dust every thing to improve performance after erasing the hard drive and having a lot of problems. I left it overnight before re-building the next day, now all I get is fan noise when powering up, no boot up or chimes. my question is would the lack of power to the memory left over night be the cause, ie, nothing to boot from?, and would booting up from an external drive be the answer?

I was thinking of making a bootable macos high sierra copy from my Macbook on an external hard drive and trying to boot from this.

PRAM battery was changed in the last few days.

Comment: Memory doesn't care about down-time between boot ups. That's not the issue. When was the last time the PRAM battery was changed? If the answer is 'more than 5 years' that's your first cheap 'fix'. See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325307/mac-pro-3-1-boot-fail-diagnosis with a great work-through from Monomeeth - even though I found the fail-point myself. After the battery, next check is the light sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The chime on a Mac (of that era) is an indication that the core hardware is working correctly. No chime means that there is some hardware problem.

If it was simply a question of no bootable drive, then you would get the chime, followed by a flashing question mark on the screen.

I would re-open it and make sure that you have correctly re-seated the RAM and other components, after your strip-down. If you unplugged any internal cables, make sure they are all re-connected.

You might want to follow an iFixit guide for stripping down your model of Mac, which may also provide notes about common re-assembly problems.