# 2008 Mac Pro no output

Tags: mac-pro

My 2008 Mac Pro will not output video. It will chime but nothing appears on screen. I've tried replacing the graphics card with one that's compatible with this mac and still nothing appears on screen. I don't suspect it's a RAM issue as it chimes.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: When you say 'compatible', what precisely was it? There are some cards that will work on an 09 or 10 but not the 08. Did you reset SMC each time. Have you changed the PRAM battery? Can you tell us what the light sequence is on the motherboard [with & without button-press] See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325307/mac-pro-3-1-boot-fail-diagnosis for a good workthrough

Comment: +1 for the PRAM battery. An old client had a misbehaving '08 Mac Pro and a simple battery fixed a lot that was going wrong. The internal LED sequence is a good troubleshooting tip. I'd forgotten that.

Answer (score -2):

unfortunately it’s likely the main logic board, which is prohibitively expensive unless you have either AppleCare+ or some other insurance ☹☹☹☹

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "Prohibitively expensive"?? You can buy a whole new 8-core 08 for £$€ 250 AppleCare wasn't even invented when these Macs were new